# Convert C++ code to PHP?

Tags: php, c++

I am trying to write a struct in php, i know there is no such thing in php, but at least get it working somehow...

C++:

```
 // The struct
    typedef struct data
    {
        char numbers[20];
        char numbers2[50];
        char number3[6];
        char sometext[100];
    }data_t;

    data_t config;

    char numbers[20] = "12345.12345";
    char numbers3[6] = "12345";
    char sometext[100] = "asdsadsad";

    // Storing into struct
    strcpy_s(config.numbers, numbers);
    strcpy_s(config.numbers3, numbers3);
    strcpy_s(config.sometext, sometext);

    // Serializing struct to test.dat
    ofstream output_file("test.dat", ios::binary);
    output_file.write((char*)&config, sizeof(config));
    output_file.close();

    // Reading from it
    ifstream input_file("test.dat", ios::binary);
    input_file.read((char*)&master, sizeof(master));

    cout << "NUMBERS : " << master.numbers << endl;
    cout << "NUMBERS3 : " << master.numbers3 << endl;
    cout << "SOMETEXT : " << master.sometext << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;
```

Now storing with c++ in the struct, then reading it works just fine, but i want to store in that file trough php, then read it from c++, so i have:

PHP:

```
$data = Array();
$data['numbers'] = "12345.12345";
$data['numbers3'] = "12345";
$data['sometext'] = "abcdfghs";

$fp=fopen("test.dat","wb") or die("Stop! i kill you...");
foreach($data as $key => $value){
echo 'written:'.$value;
fwrite($fp,$value."\t");
}
```

Now what is happening is:

```
NUMBERS : 12345.12345  12345   abcdfghs
NUMBERS3 :
SOMETEXT :
```

So as you can see, it`s not good, also i noticed a difference when writing to file from c++ (contains binary data), while writing to file from php is just plain text.

Some help would be apreciated, many thanks!

Comment: maybe `fwrite($fp,$key. ' : '. $value .'\n');`

Comment: @Toumash I don`t think adding a line break will solve this :(

Comment: The output is really: "NUMBERS : ..."? 
As it seems that you did not print the index; You should use @Toumash 's advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your C++ struct allocates 20 bytes for the `numbers` member. That means when you write it to the file, all 20 bytes are written, the writing doesn't just stop after writing `12345.12345`. Your PHP code, on the other hand, writes exactly what is in `$data['numbers']` and stops immediately (well, after adding a useless `"\t"`). The "binary data" you noticed in the file is just the garbage which happened to be in memory in those leftover bytes after `12345.12345`. Same goes for the other fields.
2. Your PHP code does not write the string's terminating NULL to the file.
3. Your PHP code does not write the `numbers2` member to the file.

You need to ensure the PHP code writes the terminating NULL, pads the output to the same size as the field has in the C++ struct, and outputs the fields in the same order as the C++ struct. You can use [`pack()`](https://secure.php.net/pack) for this:

```php
<?php

$data = array();
$data['numbers'] = "12345.12345";
$data['numbers2'] = '';
$data['numbers3'] = "12345";
$data['sometext'] = "abcdfghs";

$packed = pack('a20a50a6a100', $data['numbers'], $data['numbers2'], $data['numbers3'], $data['sometext']);

$written = file_put_contents("test.dat", $packed);
if($written === false) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to write data to file!");
} else if($written !== strlen($packed)) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Writing to file was not complete!");
}
```

---

Note: For maximum compatibility, you should read/write each struct member to the file *individually* in a consistent order on both sides. Otherwise you can have problems due to C++ field padding/alignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still wonder why people downvote my question...